# I don't know how to get text from not close tag using beautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<hr class="calibre2" />
<h3 class="calibre5">-ibility</h3> (in nouns 构成名词) ： <br      
class="calibre4" />
<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ 
capability 能力 </span></p></blockquote>

<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ 
responsibility 责任 </span></p></blockquote>

<hr class="calibre2" />

<h3 id="calibre_link-1" class="calibre5">-able</h3> □<span 
class="bold"><span class="italic"><span class="calibre_2"> suffix</span>
</span></span> (in adjectives 构成形容词) <br class="calibre4" />

 <span class="bold">『1』</span>that can or must be 可…的；能…的；应…的 ：  
 <br class="calibre4" />

 <blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span 
 class="italic">◊ calculable 能计算的 </span></p></blockquote>


 <blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span   
 class="italic">◊ taxable 应纳税的 </span></p></blockquote>


 <span class="bold">『2』</span>having the quality of 具有…性质的 ： <br 
 class="calibre4" />

 <span class="bold"><span class="calibre_3">-ability, -ibility </span>
 </span>

 <hr class="calibre2" />
 <h3 class="calibre5">-ible</h3> □<span class="bold"><span 
 class="italic"><span class="calibre_2"> suffix</span></span></span> (in 
 adjectives 构成形容词) <br class="calibre4" />

 <blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span 
 class="italic">◊ comfortable 舒适 </span></p></blockquote>

 <blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span 
  class="italic">◊ changeable 易变 </span></p></blockquote>
  <span class="bold"><span class="calibre_3">-ability, -ibility </span>
  </span>
  <hr class="calibre2" />
  <h3 class="calibre5">-acy</h3> ⇒ <span class="bold"><a    
  href="#calibre_link-3">-cy</a></span>
  <br class="calibre4" /> □<span class="bold"><span  
  class="italic"><span     class="calibre_2"> suffix</span></span>  
  </span> 

  <blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span 
  class="italic">◊ chaplaincy 专职司铎的职位 </span></p></blockquote>


  <hr class="calibre2" />

  <h3 class="calibre5">-age</h3> □<span class="bold"><span 
  class="italic"><span class="calibre_2"> suffix</span></span></span> 
  (in nouns 构成名词) <br class="calibre4" />
```

Above code is I use Calibre to transfer from a English dictionary into html and then extract into html, but they they only add some none close tag, as you can see, between `<hr class = 'calibre2'>... <hr class = 'calibre2'>` content is I need, like: I want to get like: (word: meaning:), inside h3 is the words, and easily to get use `beautifulsoup.findall('h3').text`, and right now I know how to get between `<hr>.. <hr>` contents, but only contents, I don't know how to get only text. because `<hr>` is not a close tag, so I couldn't directly use tag.text to get. 
So, I think maybe I could use wrap or new_tag, but seems not work for me maybe I misuse them, I want to add `<div class= num>` sth, between the 2 tag, so I could directly get it. and use tag.text to get them.
thank you.

Comment: Can you add what you want as output?

Comment: sorry, it looks like little mass, I want output the word defintion after the h3 tag but before the hr tag, which have defintion for the words and maybe have some example of the words.